# Is resolve, reject keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(allWentWell) {
    resolve('All things went well!');
  } else {
    reject('Something went wrong');
  }
});
```

Can I change `resolve` to `res`? Or does resolve have special meaning here?

Comment: No, they are not keywords. Yes, you can change it to anything you want.

Comment: I prefer `new Promise((yay,nay) => condition ? yay() : nay())` *tongue-in-cheek*

Comment: @Adam, yay('foo') basically means foo is the return value of the promise, right?

Answer (score 5):

No they aren't keywords you can name them whatever you want, but IMO you should keep the names as descriptive as possible.

```js
const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  if(true) {
    res('All things went well!');
  } else {
    rej('Something went wrong');
  }
});

promise.then(val=> console.log(val))
```

Comment: Whatever inside resolve is the return value, right? i.e., in your above example, res('All things went well!'); makes the promise return the string of 'All things went well!', right?

Answer (score 3):

No. The `Promise` constructor expects a function and will pass two arguments to it: the first one being a function that resolves the promise, and the second one being a function that rejects the promise. With that being said, you can name these arguments anything you want, but they must be in the correct order.

```
const myFunction = function (x, y) {
  if (allWentWell) {
    x('All things went well!')
  } else {
    y('Something went wrong')
  }
}

new Promise(myFunction)
```

I'd say it's a good practice though to keep them named `resolve` and `reject`, as most examples on the web use it so programmers end up expecting for it.